# Understanding MapReduce in Hadoop 1.x

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am bit confused on what does the term "MapReduce" with respect to Hadoop 1.x. With respect to this, I come across various terms like: `JobTracker` , `TaskTracker` (the daemons in MapReduce). Now when we say MapReduce does it refer to these daemons  or the API which a developer uses to code MapReduce applications?

Does the user application execute on `TaskTracker` , `JobTracker`? Is MapReduce itself a run-time environment?

Can anyone please help me understand this in simple words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MapReduce is the programming model for data processing (in Hadoop).

Its implementation in Hadoop-1.x is often referred as the Classic MapReduce Implementation (or MapReduce v1) which uses `JobTracker` and `TaskTrackers` of Hadoop for the execution of Jobs and its corresponding APIs (user-facing client-side features) for writing them.

- `JobTracker` coordinates the Job run.
- `TaskTrackers` run the tasks that the job has been split into.

To sum up, the MapReduce APIs determine how the MapReduce programming model has to be written whereas the Implementation determine how the Job written using this programming model is executed.

The YARN implementation (MapReduce v2) of MapReduce programming model differs in its APIs used for writing it and the daemons (`ResourceManager`, `ApplicationMaster` and `NodeManagers`) used for execution.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. My confusion is: Does "JobTask"; "TaskTracker" constitute the run time environment? When we say MapReduce does it mean all "MR API's", "Run time environment" ( plus anything else?

Comment: Thanks so much for your valuable inputs. For some reasons, I had this doubt. So, in general the user API's plus run-time environment constitutes the "whole" of the MR framework. (Whether YARN or classic). I hope this is correct understanding :)

Comment: Thanks, this is my point of doubt for asking the question itself.  How is YARN capable of running altogether a different programs altogether (like Spark on YARN). I wanted to clear the basics on MR API's and runtime and then ask this question. Can you help me understand this, please?